# How to loop over a data frame conditionally using R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, for-loop, conditional-statements

Since I'm new to loop in R I will appreciate your help with my problem.
Suppose I have a data frame like this:

```
Family <- c('mir-1','mir-1','mir-3','mir-4','mir-4','LET-7', 'LET-7','mir-1','mir-4','LET-7')
Species <- c('hsa','chicken','hsa','hsa','chicken','hsa','hsa','chicken','chicken','hsa')
Tissue <- c('blood','liver','blood','blood','liver','skin','skin','skin','liver','nail')
star <- c('1','4','3','4','12','3','7','4','1','5') #numeric
mature <- c('9','6','8','1','7','3','4','2','8','9')  #numeric
df <- data.frame(Family,Species,Tissue,star,mature)
```

and my out put should look like this:

```
Family_ <- c('mir-1','mir-1','mir-3','mir-4','mir-4','LET-7', 'LET-7','mir-1','mir-4','LET-7')
Species_ <- c('hsa','chicken','hsa','hsa','chicken','hsa','hsa','chicken','chicken','hsa')
Tissue_ <- c('blood','liver','blood','blood','liver','skin','skin','skin','liver','nail')
star <- c('1','4','3','4','12','3','7','4','1','5') #numeric
mature <- c('9','6','8','1','7','3','4','2','8','9')  #numeric
total_count <- c('10','10','11','5','28','17','17','6','28','14')  #numeric
star_total <- c('1','4','3','4','13','10','10','4','13','5')  #numeric
mature_total <- c('9','6','8','1','15','7','7','2','15','9')  #numeric
df_new <- data.frame(Family_,Species_,Tissue_,star,mature,star_total,mature_total,total_count)
```

I want to loop over `each family in each tissue in each species`. So Basically for each family in the first column that is in specific tissue and specific species ***(without deleting duplicated rows)*** I want to calculate `total_count <- sum (mature) + sum (star)`, `star_total <- sum (star)` , `mature_total <- sum (mature)` *** with adding one extra column *** called `rpm_mature` which can be calculated in this way `rpm_mature <- mature_total/total_count*10^6` (this column is not included in my output here). So for the rows that have similar family in similar tissue in similar species the calculation for those duplicated rows should be same. Maybe I described not in a good way but if you look at the output that can make sense. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach - in case it might be helpful:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate_at(c("star", "mature"), as.numeric) %>%
  group_by(Family, Species, Tissue) %>%
  mutate(total_count = sum(mature) + sum(star),
         star_total = sum(star),
         mature_total = sum(mature),
         rpm_mature = mature_total/total_count*10^6)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 10 x 9
# Groups:   Family, Species, Tissue [8]
   Family Species Tissue  star mature total_count star_total mature_total rpm_mature
   <fct>  <fct>   <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 mir-1  hsa     blood      1      8           9          1            8    888889.
 2 mir-1  chicken liver      4      5           9          4            5    555556.
 3 mir-3  hsa     blood      3      7          10          3            7    700000 
 4 mir-4  hsa     blood      4      1           5          4            1    200000 
 5 mir-4  chicken liver      2      6          16          3           13    812500 
 6 LET-7  hsa     skin       3      3          16          9            7    437500 
 7 LET-7  hsa     skin       6      4          16          9            7    437500 
 8 mir-1  chicken skin       4      2           6          4            2    333333.
 9 mir-4  chicken liver      1      7          16          3           13    812500 
10 LET-7  hsa     nail       5      8          13          5            8    615385.
```

**Edit**:

With your interest in developing a looped approach, you could do the following to achieve the same result:

```
df$star <- as.numeric(df$star)
df$mature <- as.numeric(df$mature)

df <- cbind(df, total_count = NA, star_total = NA, mature_total = NA)

for (Fam in df$Family) {
  for (Spec in df$Species) {
    for (Tiss in df$Tissue) {
      res <- df[df$Family == Fam & df$Species == Spec & df$Tissue == Tiss,]
      if (nrow(res) > 0) {
        res$total_count = sum(res$mature) + sum(res$star)
        res$star_total = sum(res$star)
        res$mature_total = sum(res$mature)
        df[df$Family == Fam & df$Species == Spec & df$Tissue == Tiss,] <- res
      }
    }
  }
}

df$rpm_mature = df$mature_total/df$total_count*10^6
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Is this possible to do with ```for loop``` as well?

Comment: Than you so much

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do, we groupby over `Family, Species, Tissue` and do the calculations:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,":="(total_count = sum(mature) + sum(star),
         star_total = sum(star),
         mature_total = sum(mature),
         rpm_mature = mature_total/total_count*10^6),.(Family, Species, Tissue)]

print(df)

    Family Species Tissue star mature total_count star_total mature_total rpm_mature
 1:  mir-1     hsa  blood    1      8           9          1            8   888888.9
 2:  mir-1 chicken  liver    4      5           9          4            5   555555.6
 3:  mir-3     hsa  blood    3      7          10          3            7   700000.0
 4:  mir-4     hsa  blood    4      1           5          4            1   200000.0
 5:  mir-4 chicken  liver    2      6           8          3           13  1625000.0
 6:  LET-7     hsa   skin    3      3           6          9            7  1166666.7
 7:  LET-7     hsa   skin    6      4          10          9            7   700000.0
 8:  mir-1 chicken   skin    4      2           6          4            2   333333.3
 9:  mir-4 chicken  liver    1      7           8          3           13  1625000.0
10:  LET-7     hsa   nail    5      8          13          5            8   615384.6
```

Comment: thanks for helping me with this but if you look at lines 6 and 7, they have the same family, in same species and same tissue. So the total count for both of them should be 16 (for the both lines should be printed because they are the same).

Comment: also the same thing is for lines 5 and 9

Comment: So after this analysis, if I unique my rows then I will have correct total_count for every family in each species in each tissue.